# Krb5.conf vs krb5.keytab in Kafka kerberos authentication

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kerberos, jaas

We are connecting to a Kafka server that uses kerberos authentication and from my understanding I know that When using Kerberos, we can provide the credentials to the client application in two ways. Either in the form of a valid Kerberos ticket, stored in a ticket cache, or as a keytab file, which the application can use to obtain a Kerberos ticket.

Here , I have keytab file . so , I have created a **JASS config** like below and have set that to kafkaConfig.

```
kerberosConfig = "com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required "
                + "useKeytab=\""
                + keytabPath
                + "\" credsType=both  principal=\""
                + principal + "\";";

kafkaConfig.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", kerberosConfig );
```

Now , the question here is **I just used this JAAS config with keytab for kafka connection and it works fine without any issue** but I found that we also need to pass krb5.confi to system properties as well for kerberos authentication like below

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", krb5.conf);
```

So , could someone please explain what is is the difference between keytab vs krb5.conf and whether keytab file alone is enough or should I need to pass krb5.conf to system props as well? or whether krb5.conf alone is enough ?

Comment: `krb5.conf` is the configuration of *any* Kerberos client (C, Java, etc) -- so that it knows how to contact the Kerberos service! Whereas your JAAS config is specific to *Java* authentication library in *your* specific Java app, but might cover any protocol (Kerberos, LDAP, basic login/pwd etc)

Comment: And a keytab file is just a (history of) encrypted password(s) for a specific account (a "principal" in Kerberos jargon)

Comment: Note that env variable `KRB5_CONFIG` can be used to override the default location of the Kerberos client conf -- that default being `/etc/krb5.conf` on Linux and `%something%\krb5.ini` on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is specific config to only the Kafka client.

The second is a JVM wide property, which is carried through to any library you're using that needs Kerberos. Ideally, you pass this at `java -D` CLI argument, rather than via code `System.setProperty`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong ,  so , Keytab file holds the encrypted token which we got from KDC along with principal and conf file holds the details of where we can get that token right?

Comment: Sounds correct to me